# Unable to set text in the TextView of custom dialog entered through EditText of an activity

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText user;
String name;
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
TextView textName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblName);
}

public void openDialog(View v) {
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(" Custom Dialog");
    dialogBuilder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
    name = user.getText().toString();
    textName.setText(name);
   }
}
```

In the main activity ,I am entering some text through EditText and then clicking on SUBMIT button which is invoking openDialog() method.openDialog() method is building a custom dialog for me.In this custom dialog,i want to display the text entered through the EditText having id edtName in the TextView having id lblName.While setting the value ,i am getting NullPointerException .

Comment: but here you are setting name on textName textview which is on activity view not on custom dialog. If you want to display text in custom dialog,, add one TextView to custom dialog and set name there(which is fetched from EditText having id edtName )

Comment: @techroid yes yes, You are perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void openDialog(View v) {
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);

    TextView anotherView = (TextView)view.findViewById( textViewId); //enter resource id
    String name = user.getText().toString();
    anotherView.setText(name);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle(" Custom Dialog");
    dialogBuilder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your question,i thing `TextView textName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblName);` is [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) layout property,so call it dialog section.

Basically Your logcat throws

### NullPointerException

is thrown at `runtime` whenever your program attempts to use a null as if it was a real reference.In here Your TextView facing this.
Try this way,

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);

    }   



    public void openDialog(View v) {

       dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);

       TextView anotherView = (TextView)view.findViewById( textViewId); 
       String name = user.getText().toString();
       anotherView.setText(name);

       dialogBuilder.setTitle(" Custom Dialog");
       dialogBuilder.setView(view);
       AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
       dialog.show();
    }
 }
```

I hope it helps you lot

Answer (score 0):

In `openDialog()` method you are inflating custom layout for [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).In custom layout you should have have text view,here it is *textName* which is part of your custom **`layout(R.layout.custom_layout)`** not of you activity **`layout(i.e. R.layout.activity_main)`**.

So you have to write something like this in you openDialog() method .

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);
    // get textName reference
    textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(" Custom Dialog");
    dialogBuilder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    name = user.getText().toString();
    textName.setText(name);
    dialog.show();
```